# Insert commant into python ''' string

Tags: python

I have this  string

```
my_str = '''
Hi!
EveryOne
'''
print (my_str)
```

How can i add a comment into line without print it, for example

```
my_str = '''
Hi!  #DO NOT SHOW THIS STRING
EveryOne
'''
```

Comment: A string is a string, you cannot put anything else inside it. If you want to avoid printing it, create a function of your own that process the incoming string to print, and avoid printing those that you don't want to show according to your logic (that should be implemented in that function to work as a "filter". Or completely change your idea of having this information into the same string.

Comment: you can break your single string into multi-strings. then ignore concatenating the comment one.  or implement @BtcSources idea.

Answer (score 3):

We have a few issues here.

1: The triple quote you're using here (''') is generally reserved for docstrings, not for strings within the code. You'll want to use either single (') or double (") quotes, and keep it on the same line.

2: The pound (#) is used to comment out code, but I personally don't know of a reason why you'd do that within a line like you have it here.

The format you'd want to go for is this:

```
#DO NOT SHOW THIS STRING
my_str = 'Hi!\nEveryOne'
print(my_str)
```

Is there a specific reason you might want to add a comment like this in-line instead of outside of that specific block?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Python's multiline string syntax:

```
my_str = (''
          'Hi!\n' #DO NOT SHOW THIS STRING
          'EveryOne'
          ''
          )
print (my_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

its not really useful but

```
my_str = ('''
Hi!  ''' #comment 
'''\nEveryOne
''')
print (my_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to ignore everything from `#`to the end of the line, you can use regex:

```
import re

my_str = '''
Hi!  #DO NOT SHOW THIS STRING
EveryOne
'''

my_str = re.sub("#.*\n", "\n", my_str)

# Result

'''
Hi!  
EveryOne
'''
```

EDIT: If you want to get rid of the spaces before # also:

```
my_str = re.sub(" ?#.*\n", "\n", my_str)
```